Don't repeat an extracted type from a generic parameter
I'm searching a way to avoid repeating T["uuid"] in the following interface declaration:
export interface Foo<T extends { uuid: unknown; name: string } > {
  getAll(): Promise<T[]>;
  getAllIn(ids: T["uuid"][]): Promise<T[]>;
  findOne(id: T["uuid"]): Promise<T | null>;
  findOneByName(name: string): Promise<T | null>;
  getOne(id: T["uuid"]): Promise<T>;
  addOne(item: T): Promise<void>;
  deleteOne(id: T["uuid"]): Promise<void>;
  updateOne(item: T): Promise<void>;
}

Is there a way to get something like an alias for T["uuid"]?

You can’t scope an alias inside a type like that. You could abuse type parameters and defaults by writing interface Foo<T extends …, U=T["uuid"]> and use U inside the type. You could define a new type like type U<T extends {uuid:any}>=T["uuid"] and then write U<T> everywhere. That is at least not “abusive” but I don’t know if you’d consider it worthwhile. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write a full answer when I get a chance. If not, what am I missing?

Thanks, considering your comment I assume there is no "proper way" to get what I want but that's ok, many thanks jcalz

No, you can't have a locally scoped type alias. There is a longstanding open request for such a feature at microsoft/TypeScript#23188, but for now it's not part of the language.
Until and unless it's implemented, your choices are either to make a normally scoped type alias like
type U<T extends { uuid: any }> = T["uuid"];

interface Foo<T extends { uuid: unknown; name: string }> {
  getAll(): Promise<T[]>;
  getAllIn(ids: U<T>[]): Promise<T[]>;
  findOne(id: U<T>): Promise<T | null>;
  findOneByName(name: string): Promise<T | null>;
  getOne(id: U<T>): Promise<T>;
  addOne(item: T): Promise<void>;
  deleteOne(id: U<T>): Promise<void>;
  updateOne(item: T): Promise<void>;
}

which saves a few keystrokes per mention of the type...
or, you can abuse default type arguments (as mentioned in ms/TS#23188 above) like
interface Foo<T extends { uuid: unknown; name: string }, U = T["uuid"]> {
  getAll(): Promise<T[]>;
  getAllIn(ids: U[]): Promise<T[]>;
  findOne(id: U): Promise<T | null>;
  findOneByName(name: string): Promise<T | null>;
  getOne(id: U): Promise<T>;
  addOne(item: T): Promise<void>;
  deleteOne(id: U): Promise<void>;
  updateOne(item: T): Promise<void>;
}

where Foo<T> is equivalent to Foo<T, T["uuid"]> and therefore equivalent to your original Foo<T>.  But defaults aren't really meant for this. The compiler cannot assume that U will always be T["uuid"] and so weird things could happen (e.g., nothing stops you from writing Foo<{uuid: string, name: string}, number>).
Playground link to code
